# Nested array duplication

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm guessing the problem happens because I append the same array multiple times and any changes made after are made to all the nested arrays. Is there a way to add them to an array and not get that to happen. For what I'm doing I to need about 500 different nested arrays, so doing it manually is a pain.

**Output:**

Before `append`

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

after `append`

```
[[0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0]]
```

What I expected to happen after `append`:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

**Code:**

```
testArray = []
nestedTestArray = []

def testarraynestedcreate():
    for countforloop1 in range(4):
        nestedTestArray.append(0)
        testArray.append(nestedTestArray)

testarraynestedcreate()
print(testArray)  # before change
testArray[1][1] = 2  # change element in array
print(testArray)  # after change )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `copy()`:

```py
testArray.append(nestedTestArray.copy())
```

This way each list is independent from each other (and not a reference to the first one).